# If all things could speak?

Tags: humans

Suppose every living organism **(Animals and Plants)** in this world can speak.

Would they complain about humans?

Comment: At what levels? If it goes down to the atomic level, the Earth would be the noisiest place in the world and you would rather hang yourself than tolerate it.

Comment: If everything could speak, why would humans be the most important thing to be complained about? Not really! Everything would be complaining about everything else. Humans aren't the most significant part of everything.

Comment: Non-programmatic speech requires consciousness.

Comment: @a4android I don't care if they would complain about other things. But I am asking if they would complain about humans on the behalf of human's behavior. Such as deforestation is a bad step taken against the forests.

Comment: But would a tree even care if his neighbor is cut down? Even more sunlight for him,. less competition. And what about all the bacteria we kill off in hospitals?

Comment: But I don't say its neighbor tree would not complain actually forest also contain animals in that and by deforestation their homes is are destroying.

Comment: Deforestation is just a example there are many other things such as pollution, hunting etc.

Comment: Everything. Your statement logically includes tools, furniture, goods, foods and a lot more. I bet all forms of seats would complain. From chair to throne. Porcelain throne would certainly complain even more.

Comment: (sorry for the off): There are no good pictures from the real white holes on the net. That picture what you shown were an art. I am sorry, I didn't want you to delete your question, I wanted to answer it.

Comment: VTC the inclusion of non living in this question opens it up to a lot of inherit problems, since non living things are made up of non living things.  At what level does the non living things speak.  Does a mountain talk, does each and every stone in the mountain talk, or does every atom of each stone talk.

Comment: Question does not define "thing". Does this go to the atomic level? Is a toilet 1 thing or is each part separate? Do our cells complain? Or our livers? Voting to close as unclear. Please post a new question with greater clarity.

Comment: Have the things which can speak been 'magically' given increased intelligence and increased awareness of the world too? A real world tree is really stupid (even compared to a worm), and completely unaware of deforestation which is happening a mile down the road.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think if non living things could speak they would definitely complain about humans because of what we do to them.

Rivers would complain about being polluted

Rocks would be complain about being hit with pickaxes.

Soil would complain about being stepped on.

Plants would complain about being picked or damaged.

Just to list a few.

I think however living things would complain as much because if they could talk humans would start treating them with more rights and as fellow sentient beings.

Comment: Why would rivers complain about being polluted?  They are not alive they cannot be killed by pollution.  They might view pollution like we view clothing.  Alternatively the river might want to be more polluted to kill of those annoying fish that keep tickling it as they swim through it.

Comment: @Anketam I would say pollution would be more like an illness polluting the river

Answer (score 5):

Considering here that speech is a sign of consciousness, then all things will have developed free-will. This means that on some level they will have a sense of what is right and wrong, a morality so to speak. 
If this is the case this morality will depend on as many factors as human morality: raising, education, religion, etc..

“There is little evidence that other animals judge the appropriateness of actions that do not directly affect themselves. In their behavior, we recognize the same values we pursue ourselves. I take these hints of community concern as a sign that the building blocks of morality are older than humanity, and we don't need God to explain how we got to where we are today.” says Frans de Waal about our own and animal morality.

**Answer:** for me some things will derive pride in serving Humans, as maybe they will feel part of a higher cause. Others will consider them-selves slaves to human overlords and complain about them a lot. Others still won't give a damn.